# Safari - Webkit contacts autofill button icon change color on empty

Tags: css, safari, webkit, autofill

I have a dark form on my website and I want to change the color of the contacts autofill button when the input field is empty. How can this be achieved?

[image: form example]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
input:not(input:-webkit-autofill)::-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```