# Invalid selector webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button

Tags: css, safari

I'm trying to style the key icon that appears in the password field on Safari below:

[image: Screenshot of the credentials key on Safari]

I'm trying the following:

```css
input::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="password" ngModel required placeholder="password">
```

but that's not working. Any idea why?

Comment: can you share relevant HTML and CSS ? we don't have a crystal ball

Comment: LOL. I'm very sorry for that! The CSS is above, simply in the code, and there's no HTML really, it's just an input tag!!

Comment: Here, I just added it explicitly into the question :)

Comment: and where is the `key` icon in your code ? you need to create a working example of your problem :)

Comment: But this icon is entirely managed by Safari! I don't do anything to show it at all. It's Safari's own auto-fill icon. In fact, on Chrome, for instance, it doesn't appear at all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unintuitive thing about styling these elements is that you need to use `background-color`:

```
input::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
    background-color: white;
}
```

There is already an answer for the similar `-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button` element here:

[Safari - Webkit contacts autofill button icon change color on empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517932/safari-webkit-contacts-autofill-button-icon-change-color-on-empty)

Comment: For anyone looking to completely hide this element use `width: 0; margin: 0`. It seems `display: none` does not work