# How to change Safari autocomplete key icon

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to tweak the default icon color for Safari to match the UI better.

Is this something, that can be accomplished at all?

[image]

```css
::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
    /*below works to hide*/
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    /*below do NOT work to alter*/
    font-size: 100px;
    color: red;
}
```

p.s. native tailwind solution would be ideal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. Will wrap into some tailwind class and that's it.

```css
input::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Duplicate of this question:
[Invalid selector webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734117/invalid-selector-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button)